# MAX7456 - interface with Arduino

Tags: arduino

I'm facing with issue I think in hardware part.

For software I'm using:
https://github.com/neomilium/arduino-max7456

Here is my hardware schematic:
[image]

Here is my PCB design:
[image]

I connected with Arduino and upload fonts, I can verify that because I can read from [MAX7456](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX7456.pdf) EEPROM fonts and I see all is there.

But mostly on TV I can see black screen and very very rare some text but without sense.

Not sure what can be wrong. Or what should I do on hardware part to debug it to find where can be problem?

Comment: A side note: The crystal is too far from the pins. Look at the datasheet "Figure 2. Typical Operating Circuit" Also ... avoid right angles when tracing signals.

Comment: Okey one issue as you say can be crystal too far from pins and other to avoid right angles, looks like 45 degree is better.

Comment: Are you getting the background video feeding through correctly?

Comment: You do have a number of inefficient or even non-recommended layout issues. Carefully read section "Layout Concerns" on page 42 of the datasheet, especially the comment about not running top side traces under the chip body. This is not to say that the layout is your main reason for a bad output but it does raise many concerns. Also refer to the evaluation board documentation for an example of a recommended layout design. MAX7456 EV kit: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX7456EVKIT.pdf

Comment: thanks for advice, i will check all that things i have missed.